# Parse Query String at one place in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to capture the query string code "?CODE=" which could be append to  various links and this links will be used in the advertisements on other websites.

**www.TestProject.com/Home?Code=ASCD**

**www.TestProject.com/FAQ?Code=ASCD2**

**www.TestProject.com/Tips?Code=ASCD3**

So when the user clicks on this link the code will be captured and saved in a cookie. And if the user registers on the site then the code will be linked with his registration ID.

I have written the code in a static helper class to capture the URL. I make a call to this method from all the controller/Action Methods.

I wanted to know if this is the correct approach or should i call this method in Global.asax Application_BeginRequest() Method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a custom [`ActionFilterAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

You can use it to mark certain actions, controllers, or you can register it for all the actions in your website

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    //...
    GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new MvcProfilerGlobalAttribute());
}
```