# How to parse query string MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, query-string

I have an url like this:

```
http://localhost:9562/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fCabinet%2fCabinet
```

I need to parse it to this:

```
Cabinet/Cabinet
```

I've looked through 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970860/parse-query-string-at-one-place-in-asp-net-mvc3) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572682/how-to-correct-parse-query-string-in-c) but i can't understand how to use it with my example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way would be to accept it as a parameter in your `LogOn` action:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult LogOn(string ReturnUrl = "")
    {
    }
}
```

Note, providing a default value (i.e. `= ""`) allows the action to execute even if the query parameter isn't present in the request.

Alternatively, you could access it through the `Request` property of your controller:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult LogOn()
    {
        string request = this.Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 string r = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"].Substring(1);
 Response.Write(r);
```

Comment: I've tried it, but it doesn't work. But i tried it with Uri, not with string (Uri myUri = new Uri(returnUrl)) And It works. Thanks